# How to convert to a full browser-based web development environment?

Tags: ide, development-environment

I would like to build web software, using only a browser. I'm looking for a third party service that offers me (perhaps a subset of):

- Obviously a code editor with intellisense and extensibility
- A way to run console commands

  - To run npm scripts, webpack, gulp that will build my code
  - To ssh to other computers
  - To be able to even run my server-side code in a dev environment
  - node app.js, dotnet run, maybe even apache + php
- Ideally I'd be able to have a database in that environment

So, is there a service that will allow web developers to operate completely within a browser?

I imagine it being like a VPS, but with a great web interface that lets you manage installed packages and a custom built text editor that doesn't stink, and a button to open a new bash session, or open existing bash sessions.

I'm looking for recommendations from those who have actually used the service they are recommending, not just people who googled one of the million "Cloud IDE's" or browser based text editors, which offer no other functionality.

In an ideal sense, I'd be able to work on projects with complex development environments, from any phone, any computer, or even an iPad with a keyboard, simply by signing into a website and choosing the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [gitpod.io](https://gitpod.io). 
Check it out it does everything you asked for.